# Cant get magento session in external file

Tags: php, magento, session

I am trying to get the magento session outside of magento in a file called testsession.php in the public html/root directory.
I have tried to use the following code inorder to get the user data.

```
    <?php
// Include Magento application
require_once ( "app/Mage.php" );//path to your magento Mage.php file
umask(0);

// Initialize Magento
Mage::app();

// You have two options here,
// "frontend" for frontend session or "adminhtml" for admin session
Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));

$session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");

if($session->isLoggedIn())
{
    echo "Logged in";
}else{
    echo "Not logged in";
}
```

but I get this result

```
 Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /home/name/public_html/forum/global.php(29) : eval()'d code, line 5 on
 line 323 in
 /home/name/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php
 0 /home/name/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(115):
 Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
 1 /home/name/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1265): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setHeader('Content-Type',
 'text/html; char...')
2 /home/name/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cookie.php(93):
Mage_Core_Model_App->getResponse()
3 /home/name/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cookie.php(209):
 Mage_Core_Model_Cookie->_getResponse()
4 /home/name/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cookie.php(260):
 Mage_Core_Model_Cookie->set('frontend', '5cccec0d46ce83d...', NULL,
NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
5 /home/name/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php(163):
Mage_Core_Model_Cookie->renew('frontend')
6 /home/name/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php(222):
 Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien->start('frontend')
7 /home/name/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract.php(84):
Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien->init('core', 'frontend')
8 /home/name/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php(42):
Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract->init('core', 'frontend')
9 /home/name/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348):
Mage_Core_Model_Session->__construct(Array)
10 /home/name/public_html/app/Mage.php(467): Mage_Core_Model_Config-getModelInstance('core/session', Array)
11 /home/name/public_html/app/Mage.php(481): Mage::getModel('core/session', Array)
12 /home/name/public_html/forum/global.php(29) : eval()'d code(11): Mage::getSingleton('core/session', Array)
13 /home/name/public_html/forum/global.php(29): eval()
14 /home/name/public_html/forum/forum.php(67): require_once('/home/name/...')
15 {main}
```

Does anyone know how I would be able to fix this error?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<?php
require_once ('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();
// Define the path to the root of Magento installation.
define('ROOT', Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB));
$coreSession = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$customerSession = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    echo "Customer is logged in";}
else{
    echo "Customer is not logged in";
}
?>
```

Hope this helps you!